# "Would you mind ___ these plates a wipe [...]?" Why is the answer "giving"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I saw this question in Cambridge website, can you please tell me why is the answer is "giving"?

Is there any English grammar rule or is it just based in the English sound?

> Would you mind ______ these plates a wipe before putting them in the cupboard?

1. making
2. doing
3. getting
4. giving

Comment: "Mind" is one of those verbs that licences only a gerund-participle complement (an _-ing_ form), never an infinitival one. You could call it a 'rule'.

Comment: If you check the dictionary http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give you will find that one of the meanings is **to perform an action**. Other examples include "They had to give the car a push to start it."

Answer (score 4):

First off, you use the phrase "would you mind" with the -ing form of a verb to ask someone politely to do something.

The use of "giving" is grammatical in the sentence presented.

Per Oxford Learner's Dictionay, you also use the verb "give" with a noun to describe a particular action, giving the same meaning as the related verb. For example:

He gave her a kiss = He kissed her.

So the sentence "Would you mind giving these plates a wipe" = would you mind wiping these plates.