# using of "GIVE" to turn a verb into a noun

Tags: verbs, nouns

Please attention to the below examples, firstly:

1-You can **give** me **a hand**,
2- Would you mind **giving** these plates **a wipe**?

We can paraphrase the above sentence as:
1- You can **hand** me,
2- would you mind **wiping** these plates?

I found the second example from here: ["Would you mind ___ these plates a wipe [...]?" Why is the answer "giving"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118038/would-you-mind-these-plates-a-wipe-why-is-the-answer-giving)
And, I am not sure about veracity of the first example.

Now my question is we can add "**give**" to every sentence and turn the verb of that sentence to a noun?

Comment: "You can hand me" is not idiomatic in English, it is missing a noun, e.g. “You can hand me *that piece of paper*” “You can hand me the hammer now” etc.

Comment: "wipe" suggests using a dry cloth to get rid of dust or crumbs. It is not the same as "washing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP mentions two verbs in their question; *hand* and *wipe* and asks if any verb can be changed into a noun when the verb "give" is added.

Here are a few examples of verb usages

- People hand documents, forms, objects etc.

  1. *Can you please hand over your ID card, please?*
     *He handed her his business card*
- People or machines can wipe a surface clean from dirt, dust, germs, crumbs etc.

  2. *Here's a clean napkin to wipe your mouth with*
     *‘There's no need to wipe down the grocery’, she argued.*

### The same verbs are also nouns, independently whether *give* is added or not.

1. *Hand* me that ***wipe*** (*a wipe* is a cleaning cloth)
2. The kitchen counter *needs* ***a wipe***. (the counter needs to be cleaned)
3. *Clean* glass cookware with ***the wipe*** of a sponge that is saturated with vinegar. ([LDOCEO](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/wipe))
4. She *gave* the coffee table **a** final **wipe**.
   . 
   . 
   . 
   .
5. ***Farmer hands*** *are* in short supply (a [factory]hand is a labourer/manual worker)
6. This was *made* by ***hand***.
7. Please *give* the band ***a big hand***. (a loud enthusiastic applause)
8. He *asked* for her ***hand*** in marriage. (he proposed)
9. Do you *need* ***a hand***? (Do you need help?)

Only examples 4 and 7 have the verb *give*; the other verbs are: *be*, *ask*, *clean*, *hand*, *make*, and *need*.

#### If we add *give* in a sentence it does not automatically change a verb into a noun.

1. He gave her an ask (NO)
2. Please give me the ask (NO)

The noun "ask" does exist, it's a bit informal and its meaning is similar to *demand* or *request*

3. That's a tough ask (YES)
4. It was an awkward ask for extra funds (YES)

The noun "need" is very common, there's *no* ***need*** to add "give".

5. There is **an urgent need** for a COVID vaccine.
   **The need** for PPE has not slacken.

## In short

Nouns can be *verbed* in English and verbs are often *nouned*; look up their meanings in a good online dictionary to see how they are used.